# passing argument 1 of 'fgets' makes pointer from int without a cast

Tags: c, struct, fgets

I am working on a bank management system in C. And when I run this code it give me this error

```
passing argument 1 of 'fgets' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Is `fgets` gets only ```char*``?

here is my function that cause the error

```C
void create_new(void)
{
    system("clear");
    puts("Answer the questions to make a account");

    printf("Enter your full name: ");
    fgets(new_acc.name, 80, stdin);

    printf("Enter your name with initials");
    fgets(new_acc.initials, 50, stdin);

    printf("Enter your birthday (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &new_acc.birth_day.mm, &new_acc.birth_day.dd, &new_acc.birth_day.yyyy);

    printf("Enter your address: ");
    fgets(new_acc.address, 80, stdin);

    printf("Enter your id number: ");
    scanf("%10[0-9a-zA-Z]", new_acc.id_num);

    printf("Enter your occupation: ");
    scanf("%24s", new_acc.occupation);

    printf("Enter your email address: ");
    scanf("%s", new_acc.email);

    printf("Enter your phone number: ");
    scanf("%s", new_acc.phone);

    printf("Enter the account type:\n");
    printf("\t#Saving\n\tFixed (1 year)\n\tFixed (2 year)\n\tFixed (3 year)\n");
    scanf("%10s", new_acc.acc_type);


    printf("%s\n", new_acc.name);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.initials);
    printf("%d %d %d", &new_acc.birth_day.mm, &new_acc.birth_day.dd, &new_acc.birth_day.yyyy);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.address);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.id_num);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.occupation);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.email);
    printf("%d\n", new_acc.phone);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.acc_type);
}
```

And here is my structs for the function

```C
struct date{  // structure for dates
    int mm, dd, yyyy;
};

struct {
    char* initials, name, address, email, acc_type; // these variables won't change
                                                     // so I use char*
    int bday;
    char id_num[11];
    char occupation[25];
    int phone;
    struct date birth_day;  // structure for birth day    
} new_acc;
```

I can't use `scanf` cz it doesn't allow spaces

Comment: Declare one variable per line, and you won't have this problem anymore.

Comment: What does "these variables won't change so I use char*" mean?  Note that, if you're using `char*` to hold strings, you will have to `malloc` some space for your strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `char* initials, name, address, email, acc_type;` in your `new_acc` structure declares `initials` as a `char*` (pointer-to char) variable and the others (`name`, `address`, `email` and `acc_type`) as simple `char` variables. You need to precede *each* with a `*` to make each of them pointers.

Furthermore, in the code you have shown, you have never allocated any memory for (even) the `initials` member, so it will be an undefined pointer to an invalid location. You'll need to: (a) allocate each pointer some memory, using a call to `malloc`; or (b) declare those members as `char` *arrays*, with space for the maximum expected size of their strings, like you have done for `id_num` and `occuptaion`.

Comment: u mean like ```char *initials, *name, *address, *email, *acc_type;```

Comment: how can I allocate memory at once for all of these variables?

Comment: (1) Yes, like that (if you want them all to be pointers). (2) You can't allocate them all at once dynamically; why not just declare them as fixed arrays?

Comment: cz they won't change, that's why I used string literal

Comment: `char*` is not a string literal. `"hello"` is a string literal and `const char*` is a pointer to a string that won't change. But, in your case, you ***do*** change them - when you assign values to them.

Comment: is this correct ```int* var = malloc(sizeof(new_acc) ``` ? and then use ```var.initials```

Comment: No - because that assigns space for a `new_acc` structure but nothing for the pointers that it contains. You need to assign space for each pointer, in each structure that you use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231852/discussion-between-aesha-amoli-and-adrian-mole).